# How to print Chinese fonts to Zebra ZPL printer from python?

Tags: python, zebra-printers, zpl-ii, asianfonts

I have a task of developing python script to print labels using the networked Zebra ZT410.

So far, I can print Chinese Characters correctly using "Zebra Setup Utilities" with ZPL commands:

```
^XA
^CW1,E:SIMSUN.TTF
^SEE:GB18030.DAT^CI26
^FO200,10^A1N,36,20^FDHTM1汉字^FS
^XZ
```

Now, I edited python code according the simple code on URL https://www.zebra.cn/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/ait/Network-Printing-Python-Example.html

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('168.168.183.199', 9100))
zpl = '''
^XA
^CW1,E:SIMSUN.TTF
^SEE:GB18030.DAT^CI26
^FO200,10^A1N,36,20^FDHTM1汉字^FS
^XZ
'''
s.send(zpl.encode())
s.close()
```

However, the Chinese characters on label is messy code as launching this script.

[image: The top one is printed by this python script, the bottom one is printed by "Zebra Setup Utilities".]

Are there anyone can give me advice on how to fixing this python code?

By the way, my printer is **ZT410-300dpi,V75.20.21Z,12,4096KB** and its details listed below:

```
- DIR R:*.*
- 4171776 bytes free R: RAM

- DIR E:*.*
* E:GB18030.DAT 95760 P
* E:SIMSUN.TTF 11519056 P 1
* E:TT0003M_.TTF 169188 P
- 55322112 bytes free E: ONBOARD FLASH

- DIR B:*.*

- DIR A:*.*

- DIR Z:*.*
* Z:0.TTF 125904 P 0
* Z:A.FNT 6839 P A
* Z:ALERTCFG.NRD 5186 P
* Z:AZTEC.BAR 0 P
* Z:B.FNT 7746 P B
* Z:BLUEBCK.BMP 230454 P
* Z:BLUEBCKDARK.BMP 230454 P
* Z:BLUETOOTH.WML 7938 P
* Z:BLUETOOTH420.BMP 400 P
* Z:BLUETOOTH52.BMP 480 P
* Z:BLUETOOTHCOLOR.WML 9373 P
* Z:BLUETOOTH_ICON.BMP 128 P
* Z:BLUETOOTH_NOT_AVAILABLE_ICON.BMP 128 P
* Z:CODABAR.BAR 0 P
* Z:CODABLK.BAR 0 P
* Z:CODE11.BAR 0 P
* Z:CODE128.BAR 0 P
* Z:CODE39.BAR 0 P
* Z:CODE49.BAR 0 P
* Z:CODE93.BAR 0 P
* Z:D.FNT 10648 P CD
* Z:DATA_BLANK_ICON.BMP 128 P
* Z:DATA_ICON.BMP 128 P
* Z:DISPLYQR.WML 2996 P
* Z:DISPLYQRCOLOR.WML 3189 P
* Z:DOWN_ARROW_COLOR.BMP 166 P
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out, just replace `s.send(zpl.encode())` with `s.send(zpl.encode(encoding='GB18030'))`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('168.168.183.199', 9100))
zpl = '''
^XA
^CW1,E:SIMSUN.TTF
^SEE:GB18030.DAT^CI26
^FO200,10^A1N,36,20^FDHTM1汉字^FS
^XZ
'''
s.send(zpl.encode(encoding='gb18030'))
s.close()
```